# Number changing value when assigned to variable?

Tags: c++

I have a little problem when assigning a result to a variable, this is happening the first time to me now. I call Convert() with "aaa" as a parameter, here is my output:

```
aaa

**676** *(value  from cout)* = 26^(3-1)*1        **675** *(value of the variable)*

+26 = 26^(3-2)*1 700

+1 = 26^(3-3)*1  701

701
```

And here the code:

```
string alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

unsigned long long Convert(string &str){
  unsigned long long wvalue=0;
  for(int i=0;i<str.size();++i){
    size_t found=alphabet.find(str[i]);
    if(found==string::npos)
      cout<<"Please enter only lowercase letters of the english alphabet!"<<endl;

    unsigned long long add=((found+1)*pow(26,(str.size()-(i+1))));
    wvalue+=add;
    if(i>0)cout<<"+";
    cout<<"\t"<<((found+1)*pow(26,(str.size()-(i+1))))<<" = "<<"26^("<<str.size()<<"-"<<(i+1)  <<")*"<<(found+1)<<"\t"<<wvalue<<endl;
  }
  return wvalue;
}
```

Chances are I'm missing something awfully obvious, but I cannot figure it out.

```
((found+1)*pow(26,(str.size()-(i+1))))
```

is doing the calculation, and it is doing as it is supposed to, the result within the cout-statment is correct. But the variable is substracted by 1 in the first two assignments.

Answer (score 2):

`pow` is a floating-point function. It takes and returns floating point numbers. Assigning a floating-point number to an integer variable truncates it to an integer number, so it might have been `675.9999999` just before the assignment, which will turn into `675` when assigned to the integer variable `add`.

`cout` also rounds floating-point numbers, depending on the configuration for example to 6 significant digits. `676.0` is a better approximation than `675.999`, so you see `676` in the output.

Since you don't want to calculate with real numbers but only with integral numbers, you better stay with integral functions. To take 26 to the power of `n`, better use multiplication `n` times. Since you already use a loop, and like to have the next power of 26 for every character, the best is to add a variable in which you keep the current power value, like this:

```
unsigned long long currentFactor = 1;
for (...) {
    ...
    unsigned long long add = currentFactor * (found+1);
    wvalue += add;
    currentFactor *= 26;
}
```

Also note that you don't have to find the character in an alphabet string. You can also just use character arithmetic to do this:

```
int charNumber(char c) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        return c - 'a';   // calculate the position of c relative to 'a'
    else
        return -1;        // error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still fail to see why 26^2 is being truncated to 25 when converted from double to int, but at least I know what this is about and can act accordingly.

Comment: I just noticed that you want to have the right-most (last) character to have the least significant value in your sum. To achieve this with the "multiply in each step" technique, you have to iterate in reverse direction over the string. I suggest using iterators for this. To iterate in reverse direction, just use `string.rbegin()` and `string.rend()` and increment the iterator in each step. An example can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rend/).

Comment: For floating point rounding errors, [please read this very informative article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#680). I know it's long, you don't have to read it all, but especially the section about rounding errors explains what is going on in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your input, though I can only hope to understand such articles someday. I ended up writing my pow function, which was fairly simple if applied only to intgers.